# how many ways you can take 4 integers from the N numbers such that their GCD is 1

Tags: combinatorics

### how many ways you can take 4 integers from the N numbers such that their GCD is 1

Given N positive integers, not necessarily distinct, how many ways you can take 4 integers from the N numbers such that their GCD is 1.

for n=5 and the given numbers are.. 1 2 4 6 8
the answer is 4. how to calculate it?

Comment: Do you know any properties of the numbers? For example, if I choose for the same n=5 the numbers 2,3,5,7,11 then the answer will be 5 choose 3 whereas in your example the calculation is 4 choose 3 as 1 with any 3 other numbers will work and the other 4 values have a common factor of 2.

Comment: You can just take a prime in, and avoid that the 3 other numbers are divisible with that prime? Then the statement is true.

Comment: if no one is prime from n numbers, what will be the calculation?  for example :-   4 ,9 ,15, 21,49  @Atvin

Comment: the numbers will be positive integers and they may not be distinct. @JB King

Comment: If all subsets with exactly 4 elements have a GCD of 1 then the answer is 5 choose 4 which is 5 since it is a matter of considering which integer is missing. Course if all 5 integers share a common factor greater than 1 then the answer is 0. For example if the numbers were 2 4 8 16 32, then there isn't any set that would work.

Comment: @ JB King ,  but how to calculate if n=100000 ? I need a solution of order n actually.

Comment: This calls for Dynamic Programming, I suppose. Are there any restrictions on the numbers themselves? Such as are all $<10^9$?

Comment: the numbers will not greater than 10000

Answer (score 0):

Counting $k$-subsets of $N$ integers whose gcd is $1$ is equivalent to the problem of counting *set covers*:

> Given a set $X$, and a family $\cal F$ of $N$ subsets of $X$, count the $k$-subsets of $\cal F$ whose union is $X$.

To see this, let $X$ be the set of primes dividing any of the $N$ integers, and then identify each integer with the set of primes in $X$ not dividing that integer.  Then the gcd of a set of $k$ integers is $1$ iff the union of the corresponding $k$ sets is all of $X$.

Set cover problems are difficult in general.  Finding the minimum size of a set cover is [known to be NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem).  van Rooij [vR] gives an exponential-time algorithm for counting set covers.  In general, an efficient algorithm is exceedingly unlikely.  So, especially if $k$ is fixed at $4$, simply trying all $k$-subsets is a reasonable algorithm.

[vR] Johan M. M. van Rooij, Polynomial Space Algorithms for Counting Dominating Sets and the Domatic Number. In *Algorithms and Complexity: 7th International Conference*, CIAC 2010, Rome, Italy, May 26-28, 2010, Proceedings ([Google eBook](https://books.google.com/books?isbn=3642130720)).

Comment: you can not count all subset . here n=100000,  so the number of subset will be nc4 is a large number. I need an algorithm of order n or n*log(n). @Tad